# MySQL: Sort GROUP_CONCAT values

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, group-concat

In short: Is there any way to sort the values in a GROUP_CONCAT statement?

Query:

```
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(parent.name SEPARATOR " &raquo; ") 
FROM test_competence AS node, test_competence AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
  AND node.id = l.competence 
  AND parent.id != 1 
ORDER BY parent.lft) SEPARATOR "<br />\n") AS competences
```

I get this row:

> Crafts » Joinery
>
> Administration » Organization

I want it like this:

> Administration » Organization
>
> Crafts » Joinery

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8631210/632951

Answer (score 446, accepted):

Sure, see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/...tions.html#function_group-concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT student_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM student
  GROUP BY student_name;
```

Comment: Your code is heavily relied upon for your specific answer, and therefore should not be placed anywhere but your original post. If you put it here in this comment, many programmers here won't see it, and you won't get the best possible response :)

Comment: Sad but true. :)  Is that code enough or should I write the whole query?

Comment: Did you try ASC instead of DESC?

Comment: I didn't use either of them (ASC = default).

Comment: I didn't know you could `order by` within a `group_concat` until this exact moment. Solves a problem I was having. Thanks!

Comment: oh my god not only does this solve my problem but it allows me to sort a group concat result set and use other functions to pop off the first or last element or whatever in a list based on the sort order...this is amazing.

Answer (score 32):

Do you mean to order by?

```
SELECT _key,            
COUNT(*) as cnt,            
GROUP_CONCAT(_value ORDER BY _value SEPARATOR ', ') as value_list      
FROM group_concat_test      
GROUP BY _key      
ORDER BY _key;
```