# MySQL - Order a Group By Statement With a Column Not in List

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

So here is my SQL

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709551615;

SELECT
    `event`.title AS 'Event Title',
    eventitem.startdate AS 'Start Date',
    `get_unique_items` (
        CONVERT (
            group_concat(eventstage.title SEPARATOR ',') USING utf8
        )
    ) AS 'Stage',
    `get_unique_items` (
        CONVERT (
            group_concat(artists.artistname SEPARATOR ',') USING utf8
        )
    ) AS 'Artist Name'
FROM
    eventstage
INNER JOIN `event` ON eventstage.eventid = `event`.eventid
INNER JOIN eventitem ON eventitem.eventstageid = eventstage.eventstageid
INNER JOIN artists ON eventitem.artistid = artists.artistid
GROUP BY
    eventstage.eventid,
    eventitem.eventstageid,
    eventitem.startdate
```

The `get_unique_items` does as the name suggests. It removes any duplicates.

Now each record has an `eventitem` has a `ranking` field. Each artist has a ranking, with 0 denoting the highest and higher numbers denoting a lower ranking.

How can manipulate the SQL so in the results, under the 'Artist Name' column, I get a list of artists in ranking order?

I don't believe it to be the same as [MySQL: Sort GROUP_CONCAT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995373/mysql-sort-group-concat-values) since I'm not using the function on the ranking field
Thanks

Comment: What does GROUP BY do?

Comment: Where would I put the ORDER BY since I'm not outputting the ranking at all or using GROUP_CONCAT on the table. Sorry @Strawberry what do you mean what does it do???

Comment: You're using no aggregating functions, so why do you have a GROUP BY clause in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear why you have a separate function to remove duplicates, when `GROUP_CONCAT()` supports the `DISTINCT` keyword.  I think the following does what you want:

```
SELECT e.title AS `Event Title`,
       i.startdate AS `Start Date`,
       group_concat(DISTINCT s.title ORDER BY i.ranking SEPARATOR ',') as Stage,
       group_concat(DISTINCT a.artistname ORDER BY i.ranking SEPARATOR ',') as  `Artist Name`
FROM eventstage s INNER JOIN
     `event` e
     ON s.eventid = e.eventid INNER JOIN
     eventitem i
     ON i.eventstageid = s.eventstageid INNER JOIN
     artists a
     ON i.artistid = a.artistid
GROUP BY s.eventid, i.eventstageid, i.startdate;
```

Three notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  Use them.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.
- I am guessing that `ranking` is in `eventitems`, but it might be in another table.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go - I will update question with my DB schema shortly

Comment: I'm a MS SQL guy so all this has been very useful!