# Sorting in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

**Data:**

```
id  uid     type

1   20      A
2   20      B
3   20      A
4   6       A
5   1       A
6   3       A
7   6       A
8   1       B
```

**Scenario:**

I want to group by `type` and sort it by `id`. I am using group by to group the `uid`.

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT
    type,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid) AS users,
    COUNT(type) AS typeCount
FROM
    `test2`
GROUP BY
    type
```

**Problem:**

But the order of the `uid` is incorrect, it should be in descending order according to `id`.

**Expected Result:**

```
type    users       typeCount
A       6,3,1,20    6
B       1,20        2
```

**My results:**

```
type    users       typeCount
A       20,6,1,3    6
B       20,1        2
```

Comment: Descending according to `id`

Comment: Check my answer below, this should do the trick

Comment: Yes I am trying all the answers, appreciate your help.

Comment: "I want to group by type and get all the uid in descending order"  "it should be in descending order according to id." inconsistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistery of MySQL.

Actually the engine takes first value in ASC order, no matter that you are asking for DESC by ID, so first "flip" the table, then:

```
SELECT
    type,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid ORDER BY id DESC) AS users,
    COUNT(type) AS typeCount
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `test2` ORDER BY id DESC) test2
GROUP BY
    type
```

[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfcfec/4/0)

Comment: it's giving your expected result.

Comment: No, its giving `3,1,6,20`

Comment: On my MySQL 5.6.17 returns A: 6,3,1,20

Comment: The fiddle works fine, I have the same version. I don't understand, do you have any idea?

Comment: Your second paragraph is simply wrong and the use of a subquery is unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: not agree - mysql perform table scan in asc order no matter that you have desc order request into group_concat. without flipping the table, the query will return 3,1,6,20 which is not the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @mitkosoft is already right.

I am posting this just to analyze the right expected result.

From the following output, we can see that, for type 'A' group, before DISTINCT taking effect, after ORDER BY id DESC, the rows are:

6 3 1 6 20 20

Then DISTINCT can produce two possible results: 6,3,1,20 or 3,1,6,20.

Which one is produced is undetermined and realization related. Otherwise, we can't rely on that.

**Therefore, the expect result for group 'A' should be 6,3,1,20 or 3,1,6,20. Both correct.**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
+------+------+------+
| id   | uid  | type |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   20 | A    |
|    2 |   20 | B    |
|    3 |   20 | A    |
|    4 |    6 | A    |
|    5 |    1 | A    |
|    6 |    3 | A    |
|    7 |    6 | A    |
|    8 |    1 | B    |
+------+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT uid FROM test2 WHERE type='A' ORDER BY id DESC;
+------+
| uid  |
+------+
|    6 |
|    3 |
|    1 |
|    6 |
|   20 |
|   20 |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like Sampson suggested in this post:

[MySQL: Sort GROUP_CONCAT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995373/mysql-sort-group-concat-values)

Here is link to MySQL docs

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat

Here is the example he given:

```
SELECT student_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM student
  GROUP BY student_name;
```

You just need to adjust it to your needs.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

No subquery is needed for this this.  From your description you simply need an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT type,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid ORDER BY uid DESC) AS users,
        COUNT(type) AS typeCount
FROM `test2`
GROUP BY type;
```

In MySQL, it is a good idea to avoid unnecessary subqueries, because the database engine materializes them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 SELECT
    type,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid) AS users,
    COUNT(type) AS typeCount
FROM
    (SELECT type, uid
     FROM `test2`
     ORDER BY uid desc) mytableAlias
GROUP BY
    type
```