# How to turn off shuffling of SQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, shuffle

I have an array which contains some data, I'm getting that array using explode a string the problem is it's get shuffled on every page refresh, how can I turn off that automatic shuffle

```
$cat = explode(",",$categories);
Array ( [0] => item1 [1] => item2 [2] => item3 [3] => item4 );
```

now if I refresh the page the array elements get shuffled

```
Array ( [0] => item4 [1] => item2 [2] => item3 [3] => item1 );
```

my mysql fetching code

```
    "SELECT *,  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ',') AS categories , 
            FROM subscription s
            LEFT JOIN subscription_category sc ON s.subscription_id=sc.subscription_id
            LEFT JOIN category c ON sc.category_id=c.category_id
            GROUP BY s.subscription_id
            ORDER BY s.subscription_id DESC";
```

I didnt use any code for shuffling but this comes automatically, how to turn it off?

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value){

     $lists = array();                            
     $lists = explode(",",$value['categories']);
 }
```

Comment: Is $list always the same? How is it generated?

Comment: it won't shuffle if $list is not changing

Comment: $list comes from table i'm fetching it using GROUP_CONCAT and left join@JulianKuchlbauer

Comment: thats why  the order of items chnaging in `$list` thats why resultant `array` gets `shuffle`

Comment: echo $list for few times to check whether the values changing or not after each refresh.

Comment: Can you please provide more code? How do you obtain `$list`? If it comes from the db and you have it separate, why concat? Please add more details to highlight the problem.

Comment: you are right $list is changing @Ahmadghoneim

Comment: @Ranjith You need to tell how $list is generated

Comment: `$lists = array(); $lists = ...` is pointless. The second assignment will overwrite the results of the first.

Comment: What's `c` in your SQL?

Comment: $lists = array();                            
delete that

Comment: This might be a mysql problem, try sorting the `group_concat` part. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995373/mysql-sort-group-concat-values

Comment: Thanks bro That Worked @Yoshi

Comment: Thanks all for commenting@all