# In a single MySQL query, can I return a string array from a field with an array of primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, if I have a table `Topic` with the field `who` that uses the primary key `uid` from the table `Users`:

```
| aid |  subject |  who    |
---------------------------
| 1   |  foo     | 1, 2, 3 |
| 2   |  bar     | 1, 3    |
| 3   |  spec    | 1, 2, 4 |
| 4   |  sauce   | 3       |
```

and a table `Users`:

```
 | uid |  fname  |  lname  |
 ---------------------------
 | 1  |  Jack    | Black   |
 | 2  |  Jill    | White   |
 | 3  |  Tom     | Grey    |
 | 4  |  Dick    | Brown   |
```

and I want to query who is associated with each subject, by name, my result should look like:

```
 | aid |  subject |  who    
    1      foo      Jack Black, Jill White, Tom Grey
    2      bar      Jack Black, Tom Grey
    3      spec     Jack Black, Jill White, Dick Brown
    4      sauce    Tom Grey
```

I thought the query should look something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(namearray SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM 
  (SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) AS namearray 
   FROM Users 
   WHERE uid IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY lname) AS tWho
```

which works when manually entering the 1,2,3 in the `IN` clause.  I don't even know where to begin to insert the field `who` into the `IN` clause.

Can this be done in one query?  Or will I need to get the query results with the `who` numbers, and perform a second query to get the final result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `FIND_IN_SET` to join:

```
SELECT
    t.aid,
    t.subject,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS who
FROM Topic t
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON FIND_IN_SET(u.uid, REPLACE(t.who, ' ', '')) > 0
GROUP BY
    t.aid,
    t.subject;
```

### Demo

Conceptually, the above query works, for example, by joining the `foo` topic CSV list `1, 2, 3` to the user table.  This results in the following intermediate result:

```
aid | subject | who | full name
1   | aid     | 1   | Jack Black
1   | aid     | 2   | Jill White
1   | aid     | 3   | Tom Grey
```

We then group concatenate by topic to end up again with a single record for that topic along with a CSV string of all matching users.

One other note is that we need to remove spaces from your `who` CSV string in order for `FIND_IN_SET` to work as expected, hence you see a call to `REPLACE` inside the query.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of concepts going on, especially in the `ON` clause.  But I tested it, and it works!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sablefoste Do you want a particular ordering to the names in the CSV list?

Comment: Yes, I now that you mention it, I was planning on adding a sort ASC by lname to the subquery.  I'm not sure where that would go with the `FIND_IN_SET` though.

Comment: If you decide that you want to order the CSV list, you may add an `ORDER BY` clause to `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Tim!  I just found that as well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/995383/1408137  I really appreciate your help!