# How to specify order by which grouping is performed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Having table `msg` like this:

```
id, msgNo, frag
1, 1, AAA
2, 1, BBB
3, 1, CCC
4, 2, Hello
```

I can get such result:

```
msgNo, mesg
1, AAABBBCCC
2, Hello
```

using:

```
SELECT msgNo, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), frag), '') AS mesg
FROM msg
GROUP BY msgNo
```

Question is, how can I get this?:

```
msgNo, mesg
1, CCCBBBAAA
2, Hello
```

meaning, that I concatenate strings in descending `id` order.
If someone can give me an explanation for both MySQL and Sql Server that would be awesome.

Comment: For MySQL, see GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT msgNo, GROUP_CONCAT(frg ORDER BY frg DESC SEPARATOR '') 
FROM (
   SELECT 1 as id, 1 as msgNo, 'AAA' as frg
   UNION SELECT 2, 1, 'BBB'
   UNION SELECT 3, 1, 'CCC'
   UNION SELECT 4, 2, 'Hello') tbl 
GROUP BY msgNo
```

Your query will be

```
SELECT msgNo, GROUP_CONCAT(frag ORDER BY frag DESC SEPARATOR '') AS mesg
FROM msg
GROUP BY msgNo
```

Comment: similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995373/mysql-sort-group-concat-values

Answer (score 2):

I didnt read whole docs...

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT msgNo, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), frag), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id ASC) AS mesg
    FROM msg
    GROUP BY msgNo
```

GROUP_CONCAT has similar functionality.